# How to set the max amount of items to show in an HTML select box

Tags: html, css

I have a `<select>` box with some year numbers in them, ranging 50 years back, and currently when I click on the box the options will reach to the very bottom of the screen, is there any way to set the max amount of options a select box should show before resorting to a scroll bar to show the rest? I could not find anything about this on Google, the only thing that came close is the `size` attribute, which is *really* not what I want.

Comment: It's possible with some Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason why you can't do that (sorry) is that these are usually implemented as OS native controls, which also means they behave differently in different browsers/platforms.

Comment: Bugger, too bad. Maybe my boss will let me get away with showing less years :P

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible.

You could do some tricky JavaScript/AJAX stuff but there usually is a better solution. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get a similar effect with Javascript. Is this any closer for you?

```
<select id="mySelect" 
            onfocus="this.size=4" 
            onblur="this.size=1"
            onmouseleave="this.size=1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Your non-javascript users will still get the huge drop down though of course.

Answer (score 0):

@Aistina - your question refers to pure CSS and HTML.
As **teknohippy** and **Lennart** wrote, if you can\want to include JavaScript you can get the desired effect.
You can build your own select or textbox ([example](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/ajax-dynamic-list/ajax-dynamic-list.html)) or use controls to do that ([example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx))